# "cast from 'uint8_t*' to 'uint16_t' loses precision" when compiling for STM32

Tags: c++, casting, arduino, stm32

I'm trying to port out the Arduino Ethernet library to `libmaple` for use with [STM32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32) devices. When compiling (using the [CodeSourcery](http://www.codesourcery.com) GCC toolchain). I get

```
libraries/Ethernet/w5100.cpp:111: error: cast from 'uint8_t*' to 'uint16_t' loses precision
```

around the code segment:

```
void W5100Class::read_data(SOCKET s, uint8_t *src,  uint8_t *dst, uint16_t len)
{
    uint16_t size;
    uint16_t src_ptr;
    src_mask = (uint16_t)src & RMASK;
    src_ptr = RBASE[s] + src_mask;

    if( (src_mask + len) > RSIZE )
    {
        size = RSIZE - src_mask;
        read(src_ptr, (uint8_t *)dst, size);
        dst += size;
        read(RBASE[s], (uint8_t *) dst, len - size);
    }
    else
        read(src_ptr, (uint8_t *) dst, len);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your pointer types are 32-bits, so when you try to assign that to a 16-bit, it is losing data.

Answer (score 0):

Change `src_mask = (uint16_t)src & RMASK;` to `src_mask = (0xffff & src) & RMASK;` will meet your demand too. Just discard higher 16 bits as you wish.